# Bindings already exsist for a different website

Tags: azure-devops

In details on IIS in windows server.

IIS tree structure:

- Default Web Site * Parent Root folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Applications\Default Web Site
- Employee * Sub App Root Folder C:\inetpub\ExternalEmployee
- Sample * Sub App Root Fodler C:\inetpub\TEST_Project

Goal:

I want to deploy my application in sub application folder "C:\inetpub\ExternalEmployee" but not in parent root folder. So when I browse www.contoso.com/sample I can see img2.png

my default site looks like.

Current Issues:

Bindings already exsist for a different website.

Config type: IIS website

IIS web App MAnage:

Web site named: Default web site

Physical path: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\Test_Project

Hope this helps in solving my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were deploying your app to a deployment group in azure devops release pipeline. You can add **[IIS web app manage](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0/README.md)** task to manage your web's Physical path and bindings before IIS web app deploy task.

[image]

Please check  below example, if you want to deploy the application in sub application folder `C:\inetpub\ExternalEmployee`. You can set **Physical path** to `C:\inetpub\ExternalEmployee`.

And you can click the **3dots** of the **Add binding** fields to set the binding.

[image]

- Bindings already exsist for a different website.

To fix this error you can either set a new binding for your web app, or you can try to find out which website has taken the binding on the windows server and remove the binding using below script.

`Get-WebBinding -Port 80 -Name "website name" | Remove-WebBinding`

Hope above helps!